# Reading a file in MASM

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

I'm trying to open a file for reading, read from it, manipulate the data and then write it back to the file. I have to use the `CreateFile`, `GetFileSize`, `VirtualAlloc`, `ReadFile`/`WriteFile`, `CloseHandle` and `VirtualFree` functions (barebones Windows API).

I've managed to open the file, more or less, but `ReadFile` fails with `ERROR_NOACCESS`. `GetFileSize` returns the correct file size, so up to that should be fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc

includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data

FileIn    db 'input.txt',0     ; file to read
FileOut   db 'output.txt',0    ; file to write

.data?

hFile       dd ?
FileSize    dd ?
hMem        dd ?
BytesRead   dd ?

.code
start:

    invoke  CreateFile,
        ADDR FileIn,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0           

    mov hFile, eax

    invoke GetFileSize,
        eax,
        0

    mov FileSize, eax
    inc eax

    invoke VirtualAlloc,
        0,
        eax,
        MEM_COMMIT OR MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_READWRITE

    mov eax, hMem

    invoke ReadFile,
        hFile,
        hMem,
        FileSize,
        ADDR BytesRead,
        0

    invoke  CloseHandle,
        hFile

    (...)
```

**EDIT:**
I changed `PAGE_READONLY` to `PAGE_READWRITE`, but the problem remains...

Comment: You don't suppose `PAGE_READONLY` might have something to do with it?

Comment: While this is stupid and certainly wrong, that's not the only cause of the error, I've changed it to both PAGE_READWRITE and PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE and it still throws the same error.

Comment: `mov eax, hMem` overwrites the return value of `VirtualAlloc`.  Use a debugger.  Does Windows have a tool that can trace system calls the way `strace` can on Linux?  You'd see right away you're passing a bad address (probably 0) to `ReadFile` and that it was returning an error because of that.

Comment: Even better: Changing `mov eax, hMem` to `mov hMem, eax` should help.